# Rails: How to get a applcation controller variable to my application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get a variable set in the application controller to bubble up to the application layout.

If I use:

```
@var = 'foo'
```

...the application layout doesn't know what I'm talking about

If I use a global variable

```
$var = 'foo'
```

... the application layout works.  However, my functional tests don't work:

```
# application layout
# my var is an AR object
$var.name

# Stock functional test
class HomeControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end
end

# test:functionals 
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

I need this var available to the application layout (every page).  Thoughts?  Do I need to make this a session var?

## Update

Based on a few other posts I'm reading, is it considered best practice to place these in the application helper, then call them from the layout?

```
# Application helper
def get_var
   Product.first
end

# Application layout
<% @var = get_var %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
```

This a) works in my browser and b) passes tests.  Is it best practice?  Is there an easier/better way?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Did you try before_filter the method where the variable is declared to make sure each other controller calls it and pass the variable to their corresponding view?

> class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
>   before_filter :foo_function
>   def foo_function
>   @var = "foo"
>   end
>   end

If @var is an AR object and not a string, you sure you have the Model name and column name defined correctly?

Comment: The variables are being set w/o the before_filter. In fact, the application layout can see them if I set them as global vars.  But a) I'm trying to avoid globals and b) my basic functional tests have no idea about them (for some odd reason)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried implement it as a `helper_method`?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :foo, :foo=

  def foo
    @var ||= "foo"
  end

  def foo=(val)
    @var = val
  end
end
```

Comment: What advantage is this over having them in the application helper? I know that by doing so, it can be called from anywhere, but in this case, all I need is for it to be available to the application layout

Comment: If you really only need it in the layout file, both are ok. It depends on the nature of the method, but it's not a big deal unless you have a extremely complicated project. Personally I would put output formatting methods and their dependent methods in the application helper, while keeping others in the application controller.